# Why tiny memory leak in this func related to UIGraphicsBeginImageContext?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-leaks

I have a simple function to create an UIImage with special size :

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithSize:(CGSize) imSize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( imSize );

    float r = 0.5f;
    float g = 0.5f;
    float b = 0.5f;

    CGContextRef cxt = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(cxt, r, g, b, 1.0);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(cxt, r,g,b, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(cxt, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, imSize.width, imSize.height));

    UIImage* retImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return retImg;
}
```

and then I call it MANY times in this way (I'm using ARC):

```
for(int i=0;i<3000;i++)
{
    UIImage* im = [self imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(256,192)];
}
```

It will receive memory warning several times, then crash on my iPhone4 ;(
anything wrong with the simple function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typical when using large loops that do no have local autorelease pools.

Since your function will not return control to the main loop, hence giving the OS a chance to drain the pool of autoreleased objects, memory occupation keeps growing indefinitely.

This would be a way of using a local autorelease pool and release not needed object at each iteration in the loop (although for such "study case" possibly an overkill):

```
for(int i=0;i<3000;i++)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *loopPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    UIImage* im = [self imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(256,192)];
    [loopPool release];
}
```

or you could use the newer syntax:

```
    @autoreleasepool {
         ....
    }
```